# difficult python parsing and data formation

Tags: python, regex, formatting, text-parsing, reformatting

I am getting the data from server as follows

```
dataProducer00 ==>  Collected:      37402  Answer (MQ):       6234  Text/s:    12467   Text/s[3s]:    12467  lined:       0/75     liveData:   n/a    diff:    n/a     neardiff:       n/a     diffSeq:      n/a
dataProducer01 ==>  Collected:      45697  Answer (MQ):       7617  Text/s:    15232   Text/s[3s]:    15232  lined:       0/85     liveData:   n/a    diff:    n/a     neardiff:       n/a     diffSeq:      n/a
dataProducer02 ==>  Collected:      55936  Answer (MQ):       9326  Text/s:    18645   Text/s[3s]:    18645  lined:       0/121    liveData:   n/a    diff:    n/a     neardiff:       n/a     diffSeq:      n/a
dataCleaner00[00] ==>  Collected:          0  Answer:          0  Ratio:      0  Text/s:        0   Text/s[2s]:        0  lined:       0/0      liveData:   48042  diff:    0       neardiff:       0       diffSeq:      0
dataCleaner00[11] ==>  Collected:      65214  Answer:      34567  Ratio:   0.53  Text/s:    17283   Text/s[2s]:    17283  lined:       7/15     liveData:   48042  diff:    0       neardiff:       0       diffSeq:      0\
dataCleaner00[23] ==>  Collected:       2175  Answer (MQ):        543  Ratio:   0.25  Text/s:      271   Text/s[2s]:      271  lined:       0/15     liveData:   48042  diff:    0       neardiff:       0       diffSeq:      0\
MACH0_CA_CFE_01_A ==>  Collected: 0           breaks:  0      lined:        0/0      obtained:       0/0
MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A ==>  Collected: 8248        breaks:  0      lined:       10/16     obtained:       1/4
MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A ==>  Collected: 648         breaks:  0      lined:        1/16     obtained:       1/3
MACH2_CA_MEC_ITC_01_A ==>  Collected: 0           breaks:  0      lined:        0/0      obtained:       0/0
MACH2_CA_TAP_01_A ==>  Collected: 0           breaks:  0      lined:        0/0      obtained:       0/0
MACH2_CA_TAP_AR_01_A ==>  Collected: 0           breaks:  0      lined:        0/0      obtained:       0/0
MACH3_FI_A ==>  Collected: 0           breaks:  0      lined:        0/0      obtained:       0/0
Reader_03_t01 ==>  Collected: 114700      Drops:  0         lined:        0/832     ErrorDown:  0   Lined:   0,0,0,0,0,0
Reader_03_t02 ==>  Collected: 434708      Drops:  0         lined:        0/49168   ErrorDown:  0   Lined:   0,0,0,0,0,0
```

and i want the output as follows

```
{
  "Collected": {
    "dataProducer00" : 374002,
..
    "dataCleaner00" : 0,
  ..
  "MACH0_CA_CFE_01_A" : 0,
    "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A" : 8248,
    "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A" : 648,
..  },
  "Answer (MQ)": {
    "dataProducer00" : 6234,
    "dataProducer01" : 7617,
    "dataProducer02" : 9326,
    "dataCleaner02" : 543
  },
  "Answer": {
    "dataCleaner00": 0,
    "dataCleaner01": 34567
  },
  "Text/s": {
    "dataProducer00" : 12467,
    "dataProducer01" : 15232,
  ..
    "dataCleaner00" : 0,
    "dataCleaner01" : 17283,
    ..
  },
  "lined": {
    "dataProducer00" : 0,
    "dataProducer01" : 0,
    "dataProducer02" : 0,
..  },
  "lined_Top": {
    "dataProducer00" : 75,
    "dataProducer01" : 85,
    "dataProducer02" : 121,
    "dataCleaner00" : 0,
    "dataCleaner01" : 15,
    "dataCleaner02" : 15,
    "MACH0_CA_CFE_01_A" : 0,
    "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A" : 16,
    "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A" : 16,
    "MACH2_CA_MEC_ITC_01_A": 0,
    "MACH2_CA_TAP_01_A": 0,
    "MACH2_CA_TAP_AR_01_A": 0,
    "MACH3_FI_A": 0
  },
  "liveData": {
    "dataProducer00" : "n/a",
..
    "dataCleaner02" : 48042
  },
"breaks": {
  "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A": 0,
..
  "MACH2_CA_TAP_AR_01_A": 0
},
  "Ratio": {
    "dataCleaner00": 0,
    "dataCleaner01": 0.53,
    "dataCleaner02": 0.25
  },
  "obtained": {
    "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A": 0,
  "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A": 1,
  ..},
  "obtained_Top": {
    "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A": 0,
  "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A": 4,
  "MACH2_CA_MEC_ITC_01_A": 3,
..  "MACH3_FI_A": 0
  },
  "diff": {
    "dataProducer00": "n/a",
  ..,  "dataCleaner02" : 0
  },
  "neardiff": {
    "dataProducer00": "n/a",
..    "dataCleaner00" : 0,
  },
  "diffSeq": {
    "dataProducer00": "n/a",
..    "dataCleaner02" : 0
  }
}
```

I am spending time in loop nothing is helping me.
The data obtained should be via generator , so that is easier for me to process finally

Can we do this via simple regular expression , or multiple splits , is there any generic way to handle all type of complex data.

This partially working code ,
where in i need to message and change the format again.

```
lines = data.strip().split('\n')

 

output = {}
field_regex = r'(\w+)\s*:\s*(\d+)'
#field_regex = r'(\w+)\s*:\s*'
field_pattern = re.compile(field_regex)
for line in lines:
    match = re.match(r'^(.*?) --> (.*)', line)
    if match:
        name = match.group(1)
        fields = match.group(2)
        field_matches = re.findall(field_pattern, fields)
        output[name] = {field: int(value) for field, value in field_matches}
print(output)
```

I need also need the following items additionally.

1. to skip ErrorDown
2. to have Lined as lined": {
   "dataProducer00" : 0,
   "dataProducer01" : 0,
   "dataProducer02" : 0,
   "Reader_03_t01" : [0,0,0,0,0],
   "Reader_03_t02" : [0,0,0,0,0]
   ..  },
3. Obtained to be split as obtained_Max and obtained as follows
   "obtained": {
   "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A": 0,
   "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A": 1,
   ..},
   "obtained_Top": {
   "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A": 0,
   "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A": 4,
   "MACH2_CA_MEC_ITC_01_A": 3,
   ..  "MACH3_FI_A": 0
   },

Comment: I suggest you edit your example to make it as small as possible while retaining its essential characteristics, not just for this question but for SO questions generally.

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question. Using `str.split` and some simple processing of the line should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are tempted to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

pattern = (
    r"(?:(?P<outer_key>.+?)\s+==>\s+)?"  # e.g. Collected, Answer (MQ),..
     "(?P<inner_key>.+?):"               # e.g. dataProducer00, dataCleaner00[11],.. 
     "\s+(?P<values>[\dn/a.,]+)"         # e.g. 37402, 0/75, n/a,..
)

out = (
    pd.read_csv("file.txt", header=None, sep="|")
        .squeeze().str.extractall(pattern).ffill()
        .query("values != 'n/a' and not inner_key.str.contains('ErrorDown')")
        .reset_index(drop=True).pipe(lambda x: x.groupby(
            x["inner_key"].str.strip().str.lower(), sort=False)
              .apply(lambda g: dict(zip(g["outer_key"],
                    pd.to_numeric(g["values"], errors="ignore")))).to_dict())
)
```

Output :

```
{
    "collected": {
        "dataProducer00": 37402,
        "dataProducer01": 45697,
        "dataProducer02": 55936,
        "dataCleaner00[00]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[11]": 65214,
        "dataCleaner00[23]": 2175,
        "MACH0_CA_CFE_01_A": 0,
        "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A": 8248,
        "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A": 648,
        "MACH2_CA_MEC_ITC_01_A": 0,
        "MACH2_CA_TAP_01_A": 0,
        "MACH2_CA_TAP_AR_01_A": 0,
        "MACH3_FI_A": 0,
        "Reader_03_t01": 114700,
        "Reader_03_t02": 434708
    },
    "answer (mq)": {
        "dataProducer00": 6234,
        "dataProducer01": 7617,
        "dataProducer02": 9326,
        "dataCleaner00[23]": 543
    },
    "text/s": {
        "dataProducer00": 12467,
        "dataProducer01": 15232,
        "dataProducer02": 18645,
        "dataCleaner00[00]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[11]": 17283,
        "dataCleaner00[23]": 271
    },
    "text/s[3s]": {
        "dataProducer00": 12467,
        "dataProducer01": 15232,
        "dataProducer02": 18645
    },
    "lined": {
        "dataProducer00": "0/75",
        "dataProducer01": "0/85",
        "dataProducer02": "0/121",
        "dataCleaner00[00]": "0/0",
        "dataCleaner00[11]": "7/15",
        "dataCleaner00[23]": "0/15",
        "MACH0_CA_CFE_01_A": "0/0",
        "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A": "10/16",
        "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A": "1/16",
        "MACH2_CA_MEC_ITC_01_A": "0/0",
        "MACH2_CA_TAP_01_A": "0/0",
        "MACH2_CA_TAP_AR_01_A": "0/0",
        "MACH3_FI_A": "0/0",
        "Reader_03_t01": "0,0,0,0,0,0",
        "Reader_03_t02": "0,0,0,0,0,0"
    },
    "answer": {
        "dataCleaner00[00]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[11]": 34567
    },
    "ratio": {
        "dataCleaner00[00]": 0.0,
        "dataCleaner00[11]": 0.53,
        "dataCleaner00[23]": 0.25
    },
    "text/s[2s]": {
        "dataCleaner00[00]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[11]": 17283,
        "dataCleaner00[23]": 271
    },
    "livedata": {
        "dataCleaner00[00]": 48042,
        "dataCleaner00[11]": 48042,
        "dataCleaner00[23]": 48042
    },
    "diff": {
        "dataCleaner00[00]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[11]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[23]": 0
    },
    "neardiff": {
        "dataCleaner00[00]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[11]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[23]": 0
    },
    "diffseq": {
        "dataCleaner00[00]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[11]": 0,
        "dataCleaner00[23]": 0
    },
    "breaks": {
        "MACH0_CA_CFE_01_A": 0,
        "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A": 0,
        "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A": 0,
        "MACH2_CA_MEC_ITC_01_A": 0,
        "MACH2_CA_TAP_01_A": 0,
        "MACH2_CA_TAP_AR_01_A": 0,
        "MACH3_FI_A": 0
    },
    "obtained": {
        "MACH0_CA_CFE_01_A": "0/0",
        "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_01_A": "1/4",
        "MACH0_CA_MEC_AR_02_A": "1/3",
        "MACH2_CA_MEC_ITC_01_A": "0/0",
        "MACH2_CA_TAP_01_A": "0/0",
        "MACH2_CA_TAP_AR_01_A": "0/0",
        "MACH3_FI_A": "0/0"
    },
    "drops": {
        "Reader_03_t01": 0,
        "Reader_03_t02": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: what does innerkey,values mean here, should we hardcode each of values to be extracted

Comment: `(?P<name>...)` those are [group names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). No need to harcode anything! Just change the path of your logfile (*replace* `file.txt`) and run the code as it is. I updated the answer to put a shorter version..

Comment: Thanks @Timeless, incase , if i want to ignore certain texts if it comes as wrong , how to manage that

Comment: Can you show a meaningful example and show the expected output in that case ?

Comment: if there is additional data as follows Reader_03_t01 ==>  Collected: 114700      Drops:  0         lined:        0/832     ErrorDown:  0   Lined:   0,0,0,0,0,0
Reader_03_t02 ==>  Collected: 434708      Drops:  0         lined:        0/49168   ErrorDown:  0   Lined:   0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: Do we need to exclude any row in the logfile that contain the word `ErrorDown` or is it something else ?

Comment: 2 more things required , 1) ignore Errordown 2)  split obtained as obtained and obtained_top , with left of  "/" , being in obtain and right of obtained as obtained_top

Comment: You need to update your input/expected-output in your question. And I feel your post has became a moving target ! If those requirements are this important, why you did not include them at first ?

Comment: apologize for adding extra items, will add the relevant details, i think obtained_top was there earlier in my example as well , where as "0,0,0" , how to read it ignore it was not covered,

Comment: No worries, I update my answer to address the extra requirement, can you check please ?

Comment: Thanks it works , should I split "/" in values  once again to seperate the field as _top , or is it possible within existing regular expression itself

Comment: I have handled seperately for _top ,  with another looping and modifying the json again. but for the datacleaner came up with "datacleaner00[34]",datacleaner01[35]" , I tried to remove  "(?P<inner_key>[\w\d./()\[\]\s]+):" as (?P<inner_key>[\w\d./()\s]+):  , it is not helping

Comment: Apologies for one more request, I have modified the data as above, today it failed, as we received new set of data, it failed, i tried modifying the code extract individually it works, but together it fails

Comment: `1)` I updated the regex pattern to make ti more generic/flexible. `2)` I don't think you need any loop here. `3)` I'm confused, I don't understand where the _top come from, can you explain more ? `4)`  Anyways, you need to be very specific about your expected output, thus, you need to show/explain explicitly (**by updating your expected output in your post and make sure it matches 100% the given file/example**) how we should handle the values containing a slash. Otherwise, I'm afraid, I won't be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks , This helps, I think i tried same solution ,somehow it did not work, for #3 . I have another complex requirement coming more or less similar to this , will need your help as well